# Vue router - dont change url in specific cases

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have page 403 but i want to memorise the url that cause that error.

i tryed:

```
router.push(redirect_403) // replace url to /
router.replace(redirect_403) // replace url to /
router.history.updateRoute(redirect_403) // error dont triger before and after router update events
```

```
redirect_403 = {
    path: '*',
    name: '403',
    component: v403
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution that i found:

in `router.beforeEach`:

```
redirect_403.meta.replaceState = { path: to.path, name: to.name };
router.replace(redirect);
```

in `router.afterEach`:

```
if (to.meta.replaceState) {
    window.history.replaceState({}, null, to.meta.replaceState.path);
}
```